# gstreamer 1.0 uninstalled link to & use external x264enc

Tags: gstreamer

I have installed latest `gstreamer uninstalled` via git and have it in,

`/home/ec2-user/gst/master/`

to launch `GST` I use, `cd /home/ec2-user/gst; ./gst-master; myGstProg`. When I test for `x264enc` I get not found.

```
[ec2-user@xxxxxx master]$ gst-inspect-1.0 x264enc
No such element or plugin 'x264enc'
```

As part of our normal dev build we have compiled and installed both `gst` and `x264enc`,

```
[ec2-user@xxxxxx ~]$ gst-inspect-1.0 x264enc
Factory Details:
  Rank                     primary (256)
  Long-name                x264enc
  Klass                    Codec/Encoder/Video
  Description              H264 Encoder
  Author                   Josef Zlomek <josef.zlomek@itonis.tv>, Mark Nauwelaerts <mnauw@users.sf.net>

Plugin Details:
  Name                     x264
  Description              libx264-based H264 plugins
  Filename                 /home/myBin/lib/gstreamer-1.0/libgstx264.so
```

Compiling the source, no problems are reported, however when running the program at `gst_element_factory_make ("x264enc", "myX264");` we get,

```
GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_bin_add: assertion 'GST_IS_ELEMENT (element)' failed
```

At first I copied `/home/myBin/lib/gstreamer-1.0/libgstx264.so` to `/home/ec2-user/gst/test_libs/libgstx264.so` and added`LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/ec2-user/gst/test_libs:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to `master/gstreamer/scripts/gst-uninstalled`

How/what do I update under the `/home/ec2-user/gst` to include the `x264enc` element?

Answer (score 0):

As I can't make comments, some remarks:

In my point of view the problem is that when trying to compile the **GST_Head** some library is missing and refuses to compile x264 plugin.

This plugin `(x264->x264enc)` is located at `gst-plugins-ugly` library.

In my computer, for example `(gstreamer unninstaled 1.10.1 version)`, if I launch `./autogen.sh` or `./configure`, referring to the `x264` plugin, it prints me the next stuff:

```
configure: *** checking feature: x264 plug-in ***
configure: *** for plug-ins: x264 ***
checking for X264... yes
configure: *** These plugins will be built: x264
checking that generated files are newer than configure... done
```

It is printing the same to you?

You should also check that `x264` and `libx264-*` libraries are correctly installed on your system, otherwise the configure will not compile `x264` plugin.

Hope this helps.

Comment: that is the weird bit, if I try with `uninstalled` I get `checking for X264... no` if I use the normal installed I get `checking for X264... yes` same as you. I guess the uninstalled script is overwriting some location vars and is ignoring the system vars for the installed directories.

Comment: I suppose that `./gst-master` script is the `gst-uninstalled` script from the `/gstreamer/scripts` folder.

Have you changed within this script, the **MYGST** variable to point to your gstreamer git checkouts folder?

Comment: If you run `gst-inspect-1.0` in the uninstalled environment how many plugins and features are showing up?